# How to Evaluate this Summation to Find a Closed Form

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions, closed-form

While taking the incomplete Bell Polynomil of $x^a$ i found out that:

$$
B_{n,k}^{x^a}(x) = x^{ak-n} \sum_{m=0}^k \frac{(am)!(-1)^{k-m}}{m!(k-m)!(am-n)!}
$$

Now, what i am wondering is, what is the valuue of this summation?

What i have done so far:

I figured out when $a=2$ by finding the incomplete Bell Polynomial of $x^2$ by doing the following:

$$
(x+z)^2 - x^2 = z(2x+z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!} \frac{d^n}{dx^n}[x^2]
$$

$$
z^k(2x+z)^k = \sum_{n \geq k} Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x)z^n = \frac{k!}{n!}B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)
$$

Note that:

$$
Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x) = \frac{k!}{n!}B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)
$$

$$
[z^n]z^k(2x+z)^k = (2x)^{k}[z^{n-k}](1+\frac{z}{2x})^k
$$

$$
[z^{n-k}](1+\frac{z}{2x})^k = [z^{n-k}]\sum_{j=0}^k {k \choose j} \left(\frac{z}{2x}\right)^j = {n-1 \choose n-k}\frac{1}{2x^{n-k}}
$$
Therefore:

$$
(2x)^k[z^{n-k}](1+\frac{z}{2x})^k = (2x)^{2k-n}{n-1 \choose n-k}
$$

With this info we know that $Y^{\Delta}(n,k,x) = \frac{k!}{n!}B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x)$ therefore:

$$
B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x) = \frac{n!}{k!} (2x)^{2k-n} {n-1 \choose n-k}
$$

And with our prevous formula $a=2$ we find:
$$
B_{n,k}^{x^2}(x) = x^{2k-n} \sum_{m=0}^k \frac{(2m)!(-1)^{k-j}}{m!(k-m)!(2m-n)!}
$$

Therefore

$$
 x^{2k-n} \sum_{m=0}^k \frac{(2m)!(-1)^{k-j}}{m!(k-m)!(2m-n)!} = \frac{n!}{k!} (2x)^{2k-n} {n-1 \choose n-k}
$$

$$
\sum_{m=0}^k \frac{(2m)!(-1)^{k-j}}{m!(k-m)!(2m-n)!} = \frac{n!}{k!} 2^{2k-n} {n-1 \choose n-k}
$$
or
$$
\sum_{m=0}^k {k \choose m}{2m \choose n} (-1)^{k-j} = 2^{2k-n}{n-1 \choose n-k}
$$

Also there is a problem when $a=1$, where the sum itself will be very weird...

Answer (score 0):

$$B_{n,k}^{x^{a}}(x)=x^{ak-n}\sum_{\pi_{n,k}(j_{1},j_{2},...,j_{n-k+1})}n!\prod_{i=1}^{n}\frac{\left(a^{\underline{i}}\right)^{j_{i}}}{i!^{j_{i}}j_{i}!}$$

$\pi_{n,k}(j_{1},j_{2},...,j_{n-k+1})$: partitions of integer $n$ into exactly $k$ parts

$a^{\underline{i}}$: falling factorial